# Tab-completion for V8 interpreter?

Tags: javascript, v8

I'm using V8 javascript interpreter on the command line but it has no tab-completion.

Is it possible to add it somehow?

Comment: if you don't need exactly v8, you can use node.js, which is running on top of v8. its interactive shell has very good completion support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you mean the `shell` sample? (`scons sample=shell`).  It doesn't support tab completion out of the box (there's no config option, etc.), but if you are comfortable with C/C++, it should be relatively trivial to enhance it to add tab completion using [GNU Readline](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html).

Likely it doesn't use `readline` by default because of licensing issues (and why introduce the dependency for a sample), but that doesn't stop you from supporting it in your installation.

Comment: Not really - the interactive interpreter is just a sample, not a generally supported tool, so it's not feature rich (plus, more features would make the code potentially harder to read, thus defeating its' usefulness as a sample).

Answer (score 2):

The example 'shell' is a toy application only meant to demo v8 development.

These instructions show how to build `d8` (the v8 developer console) with readline support. This will work for Ubuntu/Debian. For other distributions, you will need to replace the apt-get command with whatever package tool you have available.

```
sudo apt-get install svn scons libreadline-dev
svn co http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk v8
cd v8/
scons console=readline d8
```

More complete documentation here: http://code.google.com/apis/v8/build.html

Comment: there's no autocomplation as well (just basic readline features like history)